# excel vba loop - repeat a command till somewhere

Tags: vba, excel, loops

Hello I would like to have a function that, every time I click in a certain cell (E6) it will lock cells on the left (A6:C6) or (E7) will lock (A7:C7).

[Example of my sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewCtM.png)

I do not really know VBA I just need this one function.

I need to have this for as many cells as i want - for example every E2:E1000 will lock the row on the left from A2:C2, A3:C3 and so on...

```
Sub ProtectTheSheet()
    Dim chCell As Range
    Dim chRng As Range

    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="password"
    Set chRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A6:C6")

    'Check cell value in body and lock cells with content
    For Each chCell In chRng.Cells
        chCell.Locked = (chCell.Value <> "")
    Next chCell

    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="password"

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E6")) Is Nothing Then
            Call ProtectTheSheet
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Thank you guys very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, by reading you question, that the next code will solve your problem:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Selection.Count = 1 And Selection.Column = 5 Then
        ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="password"
        For col = 1 To 3
            ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(Selection.Row, col).Locked = True
        Next col
        ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="password"
    End If
End Sub
```

Please note that, in this case, you don't need `ProtectTheSheet` subroutine.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, it did the job, but I would like to also have the function that it will only lock the cells which are filled in

Comment: Since you want to check only 3 cells, do it intuitively: instead of  `If Selection.Count = 1 And Selection.Column = 5 Then` use the line `If Selection.Count = 1 And Selection.Column = 5 And ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(Selection.Row, 1).Value <> "" And ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(Selection.Row, 2).Value <> "" And ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(Selection.Row, 3).Value <> "" Then`

Comment: If you wan't to check each cell individually use the line `If ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(Selection.Row, col).Value = "" Then` before `ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(Selection.Row, col).Locked = True` (and, of course, `End If` next to it).

Comment: Yes that is it!! Just a small detail, when I select all (ctrl +A) it gives me error... is there any way, how to avoid this?

Comment: Place `On Error Resume Next` right after you start the sub.